# Possible to expose or reproduce entire Chatter UI in VisualForce?

Tags: visualforce, chatter

Is it possible to expose (or construct) the full Chatter UI (i.e., the Chatter tab) in a Visualforce page?  The `<chatter:newsfeed>` component produces the basic feed, but without the options that normally appear on the left in the Chatter tab.   For example:

[image: Standard Chatter UI]

The options inside the red box (different feed views, People, Groups, Files, Topics) do not appear with `<chatter:newsfeed>`.  Is there any way to generate them easily with a chatter tag?  I need to embed this entire UI into a custom skinned page along side other content.  I can't use an `IFRAME` as I need to apply custom styles.

I have done some experimenting with site-wide styling using communities, so I know that can reskin the native UI (`/_ui/core/chatter/ui/ChatterPage`) using CSS to get the look I need, but I'd still need to get other content into the page.  I'd much rather build this in a VF Page.

Option two is to reproduce the missing navigation elements, however, I'm not sure it's possible.  I haven't found a way to display the 'To Me', 'Bookmarked' or 'All Company' feed; likewise I'm guessing I'd have to reproduce the 'People', 'Groups', 'Files', and 'Topics' UIs from whole cloth.  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: http://cloudcatamaran.com/2014/01/customer-community-customization-part-3/

Comment: Can you please post sample code if you were able to reproduce Chatter UI in visualforce page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to show all those feeds, including "To Me," "Bookmarked," and "All Company" using the ConnectAPI classes.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_connect_api.htm

That will have everything you need to create the views. Is it a lot of code? Absolutely. So I guess you are correct that it is "from whole cloth," but at least you can reuse Visualforce Components to show feeds since you're going to use Visualforce instead of regular html.

Answer (score 0):

It is Possible to replicate all the features as shown in screenshot via Connect Api [methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods)

[Here](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/connect-in-apex-pilot) is the best code recipes provided which uses chatter in apex(i.e Connect Api) to display the chatter Feeds.
You will be able to extend it to achieve all your requisite.

Thanks